# how to display half modalView just above the tabBarController?

Tags: ios, navigationcontroller, tabbarcontroller

I'm using tabBarController and navigationController
I'm displaying a Half ModalView as child over one of the viewControllers of the TabBarController. 
Note I'm using iPhone-5 simulator. My problem is that the topViewController height is 504 even though it should be 568 I can't determine the right position to display it just above the tabBar.

```
UIViewController *viewCon =  [(UINavigationController*)[tabBarController selectedViewController] topViewController];

     UIViewController*vc=[tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
        NSLog(@"vc,%f",vc.view.frame.size.height);// prints 568

        if (viewCon.childViewControllers.count == 0) {

        UIStoryboard* story = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
        _modal = [story instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HalfModal"];
        [viewCon addChildViewController:_modal];

        _modal.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, screenHeight ,screenWidth, screenHeight);

        NSLog(@"TopviewController height ,%f",CGRectGetHeight(viewCon.view.frame));//prints 504

        frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight);
        _view2 = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:frame];

        [viewCon.view addSubview:_view2];
        [viewCon.view addSubview:_modal.view];

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                         animations:^{
                             [_view2 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:0.5]];                             

                             _modal.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, screenHeight/2, 320, 284);

                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                             [_modal didMoveToParentViewController:viewCon];
                         }];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all I would recommend to avoid things like this

```
CGRectMake(0, screenHeight/2, 320, 284);
```

(constants for settings sizes/positions of elements), you must calculate it from UIScreen object.

```
CGFloat screenWidth = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width
```

And second: if you want to display top most view you can try to add it to UIWindow

Comment: actually i had used this code to get the width and height of screen

screen = [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds];
screenWidth = screen.size.width;
screenHeight = screen.size.height;

but the problem is the height of the "ViewController instance", which get  the topViewController of the viewControllers, its height is 504.
while the "vc instance" give the right height, it give 568.
could you tell what is my mistake??
please help me i'm so confused.

Comment: The height 504 is due to navigation bar 64px by default in iOS 7 onwards. I agree to @heximal that you should avoid adding your viewcontroller this way and add it to window instead, so you don't have to mess with height width anymore.